# Vimeo player autoplay is not working on safari/ipad/mobile devices

Tags: drupal-7

I am using vimeo player to play video (auto-play) on my website. It works fine on desktop, but when i am trying to play my video on safari/ipad/mobile-devices it does not work as autoplay video. When i click the play button, it works fine.

http://player.vimeo.com/video/********?autoplay=1

Answer (score 1):

From Vimeo support:

> Why can't I loop or autoplay my videos on mobile devices?
>
> These functions are restricted on most mobile platforms and are out of
>   our control. Sorry!

https://vimeo.com/help/faq/mobile/mobile-videos#why-cant-i-loop-or-autoplay-my-videos-on-mobile-devices

Comment: I've managed to control the player even on iOS with the Vimeo Player API: https://github.com/vimeo/player.js/